# IE: onproperty change triggered when binding the handler by DOM element properties

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

This question is out of curiosity. I am working on a plugin and encountered this issue when creating a demo page for it.

I have `div` element like below,

```
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

and a handler function like below,

```
function onPropChange () {
    alert('Property changed for ' + window.event.srcElement.nodeName + 
          ' event ' +  window.event.type);

}
```

and now tried to bind the handler like below,

```
document.getElementById('test').onpropertychange = onPropChange;
```

On binding, this triggers 'propertychange' event and thus the handler is executed.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EEGcz/4/

Does anyone know why? **I am using IE8**

The same works fine with attachEvent - http://jsfiddle.net/maeRg/

Comment: Well... you're changing a property, so why not? I guess the assignment takes place immediately, but the event is only fired on the next tick of the event loop (when your handler is already bound).

Comment: @bfavaretto If that is the case the same should happen when you `attachEvent` right.

Comment: No, `obj.attachEvent` is a function invocation. With `obj.onpropertychange = ...` you're altering a property directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the event.propertyName and you can see that your className is the changed property in the second example, but the first example triggers the event by the very act of attaching to it using test.onpropertychange rather than attachEvent. So in the first example the propertyName is "onpropertychange".

Try this modification to see how the first type of event binding is actually triggering the event itself.

```
var i = 1;
function onPropertyChange() {
    alert('Property changed called ' + i++ + ' for ' + (window.event.propertyName));
    }
var test =  document.getElementById('test');
// play with commenting and uncommenting out the following two lines
//test.onpropertychange = onPropertyChange;
test.attachEvent("onpropertychange", onPropertyChange);

test.className = 'test2';
```